# Confirm Form Resubmission

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I have used

```
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','priave');
session_cache_limiter(true);
```

ERR_CACHE_MISS. it workded but its not passing jquery submission while BACK and FORWARD browser click.

Pls advice.

Comment: Did you mean to type `ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private');`, or is `priave` how it actually appears in your code?

Comment: ini_set('session.cache_limiter','priave');
session_cache_limiter(true); its appears like this

Comment: I changed to private but the issue still remains ...

Comment: ini_set('session.cache_limiter','private');
 session_cache_limiter(true);

Comment: code look like above now. actually i need to add a page reload when user clicks BACK and FORWARD option